# Finding the differential equation, given a solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am unable to understand how to find the differential equation when a general solution has been given. Here are a few example solutions, which require their differential equations to be found:

(a) $y = ax^2 + bx + c$
(b) $y^2 = 4ax$
(c) $x^2 - 2xy + y^2 = a^2$

Since I have my test coming up, I would be grateful if someone could explain the logic of solving such a question. You could perhaps help me with 2 of the questions, and I will try the third one.

Hoping to receive some help soon.

Thank you

Comment: Well, the easiest one is b). If you differentiate both sides wrt $x$, can you somehow link that piece of information to the original equation?

Comment: Hint: Differentiate both sides of the equation.

Comment: I figured that out by looking at the answers of other similar questions. But I do not understand the logic of it. Why do we have to differentiate both sides? And how do we then get the original equation? This is what I'm looking for here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that an expression with $n$ arbitrary constants will yield a differential equation of order $n$. So to get the $n^{th}$ order derivative you'll have to differentiate the expression $n$ times, and in that process you'll obtain $n$ more relations so that now you have a total of $n+1$ relations from which you can eliminate the $n$ arbitrary constants to obtain the differential equation.

Most of the times though the constants more or less dissappear by themselves. For example,consider
$y=ax^2+bx+c$.
There are 3 arbitrary constants $a$,$b$ and $c$ so just differentiate 3 times to obtain the DE $y'''=0$

Now consider $y^2=4ax$. Since there is only one constant $a$, differentiate once to get $2yy'=4a$. Now eliminate $4a$ to obtain the DE $2xy'=y$

I think with that in mind you can find the DE for a given solution.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I get it now :)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to work out the other questions and I got stuck again.  
The first question had the solution as $y=ae^(-x)+be^(-3x)$, and the D.E I got was $y''+4y'+3y=0$ which is correct.

The second one had the solution as $y=ae^(-x)+bxe^(-x)$, but my working for this one is really messy and I'm not getting the correct answer - $y'' + 2y' + y = 0$.  
I wonder if the two questions are related? Could you please have a look at it and help me with the same? I'll appreciate it